# DispatchEvent after promise (.then)

Tags: javascript, firebase

From a web-component (a child) I need to pass an event to the parent. So, I use a dispatchEvent. It is working fine it is used in an async function (firebase.auth().signOut().then()) it returns this error:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'dispatchEvent' of undefined

Here is the code:

```
import Template from "./template.js";                                           
                                                                                
export class NavBar extends HTMLElement {                                       
    constructor() {                                                             
        super();                                                                
        this.attachShadow({mode:"open"})                                        
            .innerHTML = Template.render();                                     
        this.dom = Template.mapDOM(this.shadowRoot);                            
        this.addEventListener("click", e => this.onClick(e));        
    }                                                                           
                                                                                
    onClick(e) {                                                                
        e.preventDefault();                                                     
        switch (e.composedPath()[0].id){                                           
            case "welcome":                                                        
                const customElements = new CustomEvent("pageChange", {             
                    bubbles: true,                                                 
                    composed: true,                                                
                    detail: {                                                      
                        page: "welcome"                                            
                    }                                                              
                });                                                                
                this.dispatchEvent(customElements);          // works!                          
                break;                                                          
            case "login":                                                       
                const customElements2 = new CustomEvent("pageChange", {         
                    bubbles: true,                                              
                    composed: true,                                             
                    detail: { page: "login" }                                      
                });                                                             
                this.dispatchEvent(customElements2);          // works!                
                break;                                                          
            case "logout":                                                      
                firebase.auth().signOut()                                       
                    .then(function(){                                              
                        const customElements3 = new CustomEvent("pageChange", { 
                            bubbles: true,                                         
                            composed: true,                                        
                            detail: { page: "welcome" }                            
                        });                                                     
                        this.dispatchEvent(customElements3);  // doesn't work                
                    });                                                         
                break;                                                          
        }                                                                       
    };                                                                             
};                                                                              
                                                                                
if (!customElements.get("my-navbar")){                                       
    customElements.define("my-navbar", NavBar)                               
}
```

It is as if "this" is no longer "shadowRoot". Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: `customElements 1 /  2 / 3` should be globals.. and try **Mahmoud Youssef** answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try arrow function, the problem is the call back function you pass as a callback to `then` defines its own `this` because it defines a new scope, however, arrow functions allow you to use lexical `this`, which means it will use lookup to find `this`. so your code should look like the following

```js
firebase.auth().signOut()                                       
   .then(() => {                    // this line                          
       const customElements3 = new CustomEvent("pageChange", { 
          bubbles: true,                                         
          composed: true,                                        
          detail: { page: "welcome" }                            
       });                                                     
       this.dispatchEvent(customElements3);  // should work                
    });
```

Comment: Thank you, Mahmoud! It did work! I did not know this aspect between the normal function and the arrow function. Thanks for this explanation! Have a great day!